# Can't access Ubuntu or Windows after shut down the Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, boot, grub, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7 as partition. I was using ubuntu for some time and tried to shut down. But it doesn't shown shut down dialog box. So I again tried to shut down from top right shutDown Icon. But it hangs for a 30min. So I force shut down by Hardware Power Switch.

After that I tried to boot Ubuntu and it is not working. I also tried to boot Windows. It is also not working.

What should I do?

I can view the OS option selecting screen (grub). But after selecting an OS, it is not working.

HELP

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the Windows installation?  This sounds like a hardware failure ( HDD ).

Comment: @Ramhound It was working fine both Ubuntu & Windows, before this shut down issue. But after this Hanged Shut Down, both OS not working. But I can access my files using Ubuntu TRY Mode.

Comment: Yes.  A HDD failure normally works like that.  The drive is working, a critical failure happens, and if the system is running unexplain behavior happens.  Your inability to shutdown the computer indicates a hardware problem.

Comment: So what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Use a live distro to run SMART

Answer (score 1):

You should put a Linux live distro on a stick, Ubuntu is perfectly fine. Then download and install smart tools,

```
   sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

an run them on your hard drive:

```
   smartctl –-health /dev/sda
```

This will produce some useful output, on the basis of which you can plot your next step.
Should the device report it has no SMART capabilities, this command

```
  smartctl -s on /dev/sda
```

will turn them on.